# Fancytree getSelectedNodes without using the select event

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I am using the fancytree plugin to render a directory and next to this fancytree is a button.  The user is supposed to click this button, and I am supposed to get a list of selected nodes from the tree and do something with it.

How do I access the list of selected nodes from the tree in my button.click event?

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   // how to get selected nodes in tree
});
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
     //first method - get previous element relative to the button
     $(this).prev().fancytree("getSelectedNodes");

     //second method - use array
     $("#tree").fancytree("getSelectedNodes");
});
```

Comment: I would add my +1 back if the above was fixed to work as shown in the followup post below.

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer gave me a "No such method" error. This worked:

```
$('#tree').fancytree('getTree').getSelectedNodes();
```